# Add custom shipping carrier validations not working. Any body faced the same?

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.2.6

We just followed the same steps at

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html

Still the validation not works properly.

**Magento `CE 2.2.6` having any core issue related to that?**

Comment: Could you please mention your validation rule.

Comment: I found the cause and updated an answer. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

After digging on more on this, we have to add the following function in the shipping class we are using,

```
 public function processAdditionalValidation(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $request)
{
    $errorMsg = '';
    $defaultErrorMsg = __('The shipping module is not available.');
    $showMethod = $this->getConfigData('showmethod');
    if (!$errorMsg && !$request->getDestPostcode() && $this->isZipCodeRequired($request->getDestCountryId())) {
        $errorMsg = __('This shipping method is not available. Please specify the zip code.');
    }

    if ($errorMsg) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Where I can add this method & how it'll call?

Comment: The class which has the following,
extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface